# Is there a C# method equivalent to all powershell functions without hosting powershell in C#? (e.g. Rename-NetAdapter)

Tags: c#, powershell

How come I with Powershell can write

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Adapter name" | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName "New name"
```

to change the name of a network interface, but with C# it's damn near impossible?

Isn't there some programatic access to the powershell functionality without running powershell commands?

**EDIT**:
Somehow people are confusing this question with a network question. This is *not* a question about how I change the network name in C#, but if I can access the powershell features programatically, so I instead of executing

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Adapter name" | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName "New name"
```

from within C#, can call something like

```
SetName(adapter, "New name");
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn569260(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Did you read the question? I am asking if there is a way without hosting powershell in C#.

Comment: Did you read your own question?

Comment: @lejon: The way that David Brabant suggested seems to do exactly what you want to achieve (see you question title). Can you explain why this won't work for you so that we can help you better?

Comment: By the way, if you want to change the name of the network adapter from within .NET, you probably would use the Shell object as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10745588/40347

Comment: @0xA3 Yes. I'm asking if it can be done _without_ the powershell commands. What is suggested is _with_ the powershell commands.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10822290/520612

Comment: @0xA3 How is this a duplicate? The title and the contents asks if there is a way to programmatically access powershell functionality, _not_ how to change the name of a network adapter.

Comment: @lejon: Maybe this is a misunderstanding, but you explicitly stated that you want to achieve your goal without PowerShell. "I'm asking if it can be done without the powershell commands."

Comment: Question title updated to actually reflect what the OP is asking

Comment: @0xA3 Yes, I stated that in a comment to the question. The comment does not void the question it self.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell and .NET are very interoperable.

Powershell scripts & cmdlets can be called from C#.

Similarly .NET Framework Components & Functionality can be called from Powershell.

In your case, updating a Network Adapter name, this is a core windows functionality and both powershell & .NET would have the ability to do this, though it would seem that where Powershell has wrapped this functionality up in a nice single cmdlet, the approach to doing this in .NET is slightly more involved.

One approach would be to call out to an external process using `System.Diagnostics.Process` and making a shell call to `netsh`

```
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" newname="ExampleLan"
```

Another Approach would be to use a Registry Key update for the NIC Guid and modify the registry directly. [See this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5c3944f-fdd0-4d97-87a4-349de6d8c70a/rename-network-interface-name?forum=csharpgeneral)